# Plist is empty,unable to fill table view using plist

Tags: plist

I am trying to load my table view using plist file. But when i run my app,my table view is    empty. I created a plist file,it contains an array.But I am not able to fill the table view     with an array. I would appreciate if someone helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, we needed to change it to dictionary in order to read from the plist:

```
 NSString *appetizerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"appetizer" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:appetizerPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Solution:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PlistName" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSMutableDictionary * propertyDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```